# Memory Leak in c++/cli application

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, c++-cli

I am passing bitmap from my c# app to c++/cli dll that add it to video. 
The problem is program slowly leaking memory. I tried _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() shows me leak of bitmap & another 40 byte leak but i am disposing bitmap.
Can anyone see memory leak, Here is code..

Flow:

1) Capture screenshot by takescreenshot()

2) pass it to c++/cli function

3) dispose bitmap

lines from my c# app

```
Bitmap snap = takescreeshot();
vencoder.AddBitmap(snap);
snap.Dispose();
vencoder.printleak();

private static Bitmap takescreeshot()
    {
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = null;
        System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = null;

        bitmap = new Bitmap
        (
            System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
            System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
            System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb
        );

        graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

        graphics.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);

        //Write TimeSpamp
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(1166, 738, 200, 20);
        String datetime= System.String.Format("{0:dd:MM:yy  hh:mm:ss}",DateTime.Now);
        System.Drawing.Font sysfont = new System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 14, FontStyle.Bold);
        graphics.DrawString(datetime, sysfont, Brushes.Red,rect);
        //

        Grayscale filter = new Grayscale(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
        Bitmap grayImage = filter.Apply(bitmap);

        //Dispose
        bitmap.Dispose();
        graphics.Dispose();

        return grayImage;
    }
```

now in c++/cli dll

```
bool VideoEncoder::AddBitmap(Bitmap^ bitmap)
    {
        BitmapData^ bitmapData = bitmap->LockBits( System::Drawing::Rectangle( 0, 0,bitmap->Width, bitmap->Height ),ImageLockMode::ReadOnly,PixelFormat::Format8bppIndexed);
        uint8_t* ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>( static_cast<void*>( bitmapData->Scan0 ) );
        uint8_t* srcData[4] = { ptr, NULL, NULL, NULL };
        int srcLinesize[4] = { bitmapData->Stride, 0, 0, 0 };

        pCurrentPicture = CreateFFmpegPicture(pVideoStream->codec->pix_fmt, pVideoStream->codec->width, pVideoStream->codec->height);

        sws_scale(pImgConvertCtx, srcData, srcLinesize, 0, bitmap->Height, pCurrentPicture->data, pCurrentPicture->linesize );

        bitmap->UnlockBits( bitmapData );

        write_video_frame();

        bitmapData=nullptr;
        ptr=NULL;

        return true;
    }

AVFrame * VideoEncoder::CreateFFmpegPicture(int pix_fmt, int nWidth, int nHeight)
    {

      AVFrame *picture     = NULL;
      uint8_t *picture_buf = NULL;
      int size;

      picture = avcodec_alloc_frame();
      if ( !picture)
      {
        printf("Cannot create frame\n");
        return NULL;
      }

      size = avpicture_get_size((AVPixelFormat)pix_fmt, nWidth, nHeight);

      picture_buf = (uint8_t *) av_malloc(size);

      if (!picture_buf) 
      {
        av_free(picture);
        printf("Cannot allocate buffer\n");
        return NULL;
      }

      avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)picture, picture_buf,
        (AVPixelFormat)pix_fmt, nWidth, nHeight);

      return picture;
    }

    void VideoEncoder::write_video_frame()
    {
        AVCodecContext* codecContext = pVideoStream->codec;

        int out_size, ret = 0;

        if ( pFormatContext->oformat->flags & AVFMT_RAWPICTURE )
        {
            printf( "raw picture must be written" );
        }
        else
        {
            out_size = avcodec_encode_video( codecContext, pVideoEncodeBuffer,nSizeVideoEncodeBuffer, pCurrentPicture );

            if ( out_size > 0 )
            {
                AVPacket packet;
                av_init_packet( &packet );

                if ( codecContext->coded_frame->pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE )
                {
                    packet.pts = av_rescale_q( packet.pts, codecContext->time_base, pVideoStream->time_base );
                }

                if ( codecContext->coded_frame->pkt_dts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE )
                {
                    packet.dts = av_rescale_q( packet.dts, codecContext->time_base, pVideoStream->time_base );
                }

                if ( codecContext->coded_frame->key_frame )
                {
                    packet.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
                }

                packet.stream_index = pVideoStream->index;
                packet.data = pVideoEncodeBuffer;
                packet.size = out_size;

                ret = av_interleaved_write_frame( pFormatContext, &packet );

                av_free_packet(&packet);
                av_freep(pCurrentPicture);
            }
            else
            {
                // image was buffered
            }
        }

        if ( ret != 0 )
        {
            throw gcnew Exception( "Error while writing video frame." );
        }
    }


    void VideoEncoder::printleak()
    {
        printf("No of leaks: %d",_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks());
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Comment: Do you ever clean up after creating `new Rectangle(...)`?

Comment: I am not sure, but where is result of `picture_buf = (uint8_t *) av_malloc(size);` released?

Comment: added av_free(pCurrentPicture->data[0]) to free picture_buf. thx, but still leaking memory.                                    Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{195} normal block at 0x07248568, 40 bytes long.
 Data: <Recording\Report> 52 65 63 6F 72 64 69 6E 67 5C 52 65 70 6F 72 74
{193} normal block at 0x072B8040, 4194304 bytes long.
 Data: <                > CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD
Object dump complete.
No of leaks: 1.

Comment: Changed some lines,now printleak() shows nothing but still memory leaking.. at start it was ~60mb & in 1 min goes upto 110mb. I tried GC.Collect(), still same.( means maybe unmanaged code leaking memory )

Comment: @Ankush: As log the allocated memory goes down from time to time (when GC collects) and the highest value gets stable after some time everything is fine. Try to keep an eye on memory consumption for much more than one minute than you can see if it's stabilizing.